# Soap call using pfx or p12 authentication in Zeep or suds library Python

Tags: python, python-requests, suds, zeep

I want to use SOAP call service using .p12 certificate file. I tried below code. But it throws path error.

Is there any solution for this, in suds python3?

```
*TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not X509*

from requests import Session
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep import Client
from OpenSSL import crypto

pkcs12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(CertPath, 'rb').read(), Password)
session = Session()
session.cert = (pkcs12.get_certificate(),pkcs12.get_privatekey())
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(
    'http://my.own.sslhost.local/service?WSDL',
    transport=transport)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert the p12 cert into the pem format before adding into `session.cert`, e.g. something like below:

```
pkcs12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(CertPath, 'rb').read(), Password)

cert = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pkcs12.get_certificate())
key = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pkcs12.get_privatekey())

with open('cert.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(cert)    
with open('key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(key)

session.cert = ('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
```